# Snowflake sharing to Data Consumer

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

In snowflake share Data Providers can share data with only the Data Consumer and does Snowflake charges additional fees to Data providers for each share they create?

Also is it possible that after sharing the Data Consumer can extend that data shared to them to other Data Consumers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does Snowflake charges additional fees to Data providers for each share they create?

No, there is no *additional* charge. This is because, when you share data, no actual data is copied, so there is no additional storage required and therefore no associated additional cost. Even the process of creating the share and granting privileges for databases and other supported database objects (schemas, UDFs, tables, and views) to a share does not incur any direct cost since these are metadata operations and are thus part of Cloud Services. Snowflake credits are used to pay for the usage of the cloud services that exceeds 10% of the daily usage of the compute resources. Usage for cloud services is charged only if the daily consumption of cloud services exceeds 10% of the daily usage of the compute resources.

If data is shared outside the region where the Snowflake account is hosted then will be additional storage costs for replication.

> is it possible that after sharing the Data Consumer can extend that data shared to them to other Data Consumers?

It is not possible to share a consumed share.

Comment: Thank you very much for your ultimate reply which helped me to clarify my point...Also how about the first part which says "Data Providers can share data with only the Data Consumer".. I think this is incorrect as Data Provider also share the data with Data Reader. Can you highlight if my thinking is correct.

Comment: Also as we are discussing on Share, I would also like to clarify about the Reader account "Reader Accounts are able to extract data from shared data objects for use outside of
Snowflake."-> Here reader account can use the extracted data for use outside of Snowflake ? Am I correct

Comment: You're welcome. If you are changing the question a bit, or asking a follow-on question, please post a new one for that.  As for Reader Accounts, there is also no additional cost of storage for the same reason (there is no additional storage - of course there is a compute cost for querying shared data).